# Weight paint substraction not working? Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, rigging, vertex-groups

i am trying to remove weight paint from a vertex group.
Adding weight works just fine but when i change the weight scale to 0.0 it does not remove weight. What am i missing or how else do i remove weight paint? (I am using Blender 2.8)

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what exact process you are doing when you say "i change the weight scale to 0.0"? Are you clicking buttons, using weight-paint mode? Thanks.

Comment: I imported a 3D-Model, rigged it and applied auto weight assignment (which worked fine), i select a vertex group of which i want to adjust the weight paint and i just want to remove some of the weight paint (make it blue). In order to do that i right click while in weight paint mode and set the "Weight" value to 0. From what i know this is supposed to remove weight, but nothing changes when painting then.

Comment: Stop the presses. It is an Auto-normalize issue. Killing Auto-normalize fixed this problem for me. I hate that solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The Brush is set to *Add* by default.

In the top left corner go to *View > Tool Settings*, now you can change the Brush Mode to *Subtract*.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the brush from "draw" to "Subtract". Draw is designed to create more weight, and subtract to remove it. If it is still not working, try adjusting the strength tab. As far as I know, the weight parameter is the target weight, and the strength is the percentage of that that is added. If that doesn't work, try posting the .blend.

Comment: There is no subtract brush in blender 2.8. If the weight scale on the draw brush is <0.5 it is supposed to subtract and above to add weight.